# sprite images using mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache, debian, mod-pagespeed

```
Configuration:
Version: 13: on

Filters
ah  Add Head
cc  Combine Css
jc  Combine Javascript
gp  Convert Gif to Png
jp  Convert Jpeg to Progressive
mc  Convert Meta Tags
pj  Convert Png to Jpeg
ec  Cache Extend Css
ei  Cache Extend Images
es  Cache Extend Scripts
fc  Fallback Rewrite Css 
if  Flatten CSS Imports
hw  Flushes html
ci  Inline Css
ii  Inline Images
il  Inline @import to Link
ji  Inline Javascript
js  Jpeg Subsampling
rj  Recompress Jpeg
rp  Recompress Png
rw  Recompress Webp
ri  Resize Images
cf  Rewrite Css
jm  Rewrite Javascript
cu  Rewrite Style Attributes With Url
is  Sprite Images
cp  Strip Image Color Profiles
md  Strip Image Meta Data

Options
  tifrwd    True
  e 1
  afcl  500000
  afcp  /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/
  ald   /var/log/pagespeed
  assld /etc/ssl/certs
  asle  True

Domain Lawyer
```

also, I am using just 2 png images for test, and html+css code was copied from here http://modpagespeed.com/sprite_images.html?PageSpeed=off but sprite_images not working for me.

I am using debian7 x64, apache2.2, mod_page speed I was take here https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb not sure which version it is. Is there something external that I must install to enable sprite images filter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image spriting with mod\_pagespeed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305351/image-spriting-with-mod-pagespeed)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305351/image-spriting-with-mod-pagespeed, image spriting is very sensitive in mod_pagespeed.