# Skipping traditional pages load/speed techniques when mod_pagespeed in use

Tags: pagespeed, browserify, mod-pagespeed, web-frontend

I'm trying to determine if certain "PageSpeed best practices" can be skipped by our front-end team and build process now that we are using mod_pagespeed (Apache). An example of things which mod_pagespeed does automatically which could potentially be skipped are:
1. Combine and Minify JS and CSS (such as might be done with a tool like Browserify)
2. Compress images
3. Asynchronous loading/injection of JS and CSS (script loaders, atomify, etc)
4. Static asset versioning for cache-busting (grunt-usemin, etc)

To give an example answer, right now I have removed static asset versioning and instead have our global.js and global.css files non-versioned and with a short expiry time. This is because mod_pagespeed quickly versions them with huge expires anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We implemented mod_pagespeed for the main portal web site of a large telco. Whilst PageSpeed is a very handy optimization tool, it's not a magic wand and has some strict limitations. We did away with most of the traditional techniques, but found that a lot of manual fixing of resources was required to get everything to optimize.

1. Combine and Minify JS and CSS? Yes, but note the following limitations:

   - You cannot combine JavaScript across inline scripts and IE conditional comments.
   - You cannot combine JavaScript files that employ "use strict" (you might need a filter to strip these out at runtime)
   - Further limitations at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-combine and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-combine
   - mod_pagespeed must be able to fetch and rewrite your resources (if this is not configured correctly, nothing will happen)
2. Compress images? Yes, but note the following limitations:

   - Animated gifs are not compressed
   - There is a fair amount of tuning that needs to be applied to your mod_pagespeed configuration to get image compression to work optimally for your site
3. Asynchronous loading/injection of JS and CSS? Sort of:

   - You'll still need something like require.js for conditional loading of JavaScript. We have a server-side solution for this
   - You'll find that a lot of JavaScript can't be loaded asynchronously and you'll have to mark it with: `<script pagespeed_no_defer="">...</script>`
   - There is no mechanism for async/conditional injection of CSS
   - Also, lazy loading of images works really well.
4. Static asset versioning for cache-busting? Yes. This is one area where mod_pagespeed really shines and we have not had to do any manual fixes to get this working. However, note that mod_pagespeed can only work with this if you have headers that marks resources as cache-able.

Additionally, if you were thinking of using image spriting, note that it's EXTREMELY restrictive:
[Image spriting with mod_pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305351/image-spriting-with-mod-pagespeed)